# Display all rows with the same id

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my table:

```
Place_Id | Value_Name| Value
-------------------------------
001      | Name1     | Value1
-------------------------------
001      | Name2     | Value2
-------------------------------
001      | Name3     | Value3
-------------------------------
002      | Name1     | Value4
-------------------------------
002      | Name2     | Value5
```

How can I echo out list of all `Value_Name` for `Place_Id` 001 ?

I tried this:

```
<?php
$query2 = ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE Place_Id = 001");
if ($statement2 = $db_conn_pdo->prepare($query2))
{
  $statement2->execute();
  while ($row2 = $statement2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
   {
    $output2 = $row2['Value_Name'];
  } 
}
echo $output2;
?>
```

and it returned only the last "Value_Name".

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting your question, but are you looking for the query? `SELECT Value_Name FROM [table] WHERE Place_Id = '001'`

Comment: show you code what you try for it?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
$query = $con ->query
 ("
   SELECT Value_Name FROM [table] WHERE Place_Id = '001'
 ");

$valueName = array();

while($row = $query->fetch_object())  
{
 $valueName[] = $row;
}   

foreach($valueName as $Value)
 {
  echo $Value->Value_Name;
 }
```

Comment: did you change `[table]` to the name of your table, and `$con` is my database connection replace that with what ever yours is

Comment: Yes, but I did it with "prepare", similar  as I you can see in my edited post.

Comment: $valueName array contains everything it should, so that foreach statement do not work.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the final version thanks to @Alexander Ravikovich and @McNoodles:

```
$query = $con ->query
 ("
SELECT Value_Name FROM [table] WHERE Place_Id = '001'
 ");

while($row = $query->fetch_object())  
{
 echo $row['Value_Name'];
}   
// the second loop is not needed as @Alexander Ravikovich suggested
```

Comment: Really? Two loops for the same data? Just do echo $row->Value_Name in first loop and delete second loop!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming table name is jiggles (since you didn't mention it)

SQL Query : `SELECT Value_Name FROM jiggles WHERE jiggles.place_id = [the id you want to know]`

Execute this trough PHP and echo the results somewhere

(* in the Select works too, as long as you just only echo the value_name property)